# Method to read a message twice from Linux IPC Message Queues

Tags: c, linux

Whenever the message is read from message queue, message is deleted by kernel.

1. Is it possible to read the same message twice?
2. How can read the same message twice in same process or in two different processes?

Comment: **Why do you ask**? Please **edit your question** to motivate it....

Answer (score 1):

You can't read twice from a *queue*, reading without removing is called *peeking* and you cannot peek in a POSIX queue. Read [mq_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html).

You probably should design your software to **avoid having to read twice the same data from a queue** (e.g. by adding appropriate buffering, perhaps serialized or locked by some mutex).

Comment: Thank You for the answer